# Spring Web MVC: How to change viewResolver prefix according to client request

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have two folders inside my WEB-INF directory 1st is `views` which has desktop website related template files and 2nd one `mobile_views` has mobile website template. I am using WebConfiguration class file and define required `@Bean` functions. Now I want to change the `viewResolver.setPrefix(viewFolderName)` according to the request. If user hits the website from mobile so will set `mobile_views` otherwise It will `views`. So I am detecting the device browser and setting the `viewFolderName` but seems to work only one time because `WebConfiguration` class getting accessed when server starts, that's why I am facing this problem. Here is my code, please give me some solution for this.

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass( JstlView.class );
    if(isRequestFromMobile()) viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/mobile_views/");
    else viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    return viewResolver;
}

private @Autowired HttpServletRequest request;
private boolean isRequestFromMobile() {
    String userAgent = request.getHeader("User-Agent");
    String httpAccept = request.getHeader("Accept");
    UAgentInfo detector = new UAgentInfo(userAgent, httpAccept);
    System.out.println("### User Agent: "+userAgent);
    if (detector.detectMobileQuick()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Plz elaborate on "works only  one time"..

Comment: basically I have added this on WebConfiguration `viewResolver()` method, So the method will call at very first time only after server started to set the `suffix, prefix, templateMode etc.`.

Comment: Take a look at spring mobile! Maybe useful in your situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://spring.io/guides/gs/device-detection/) tutorial from Spring's site that depends on Spring Boot.

The meat is that you need to configure `DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor` and `DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver`.

Once that is done, you can use the controller method's Device argument to differentiate the handling depending on the device

A step further from that point would be to integrate `LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver` (provided by [Spring Mobile](http://projects.spring.io/spring-mobile/)) in the following manner:

```
@Bean
public LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver liteDeviceAwareViewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver delegate = 
            new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    delegate.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    delegate.setSuffix(".jsp");
    LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver resolver = 
            new LiteDeviceDelegatingViewResolver(delegate);
    resolver.setMobilePrefix("mobile/");
    resolver.setTabletPrefix("tablet/");
    return resolver;
}
```